# ErrorText condicional não funciona

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estou tentando usar uma validação no no TextField, já tentei como TextFormField também, mas, sem sucesso!

Gostaria que ao digitar ou ao pressionar o botão Confirmar, aparecesse a mensagem de erro ou não no campo.

Por exemplo, se o valor informado for menor do que o valor total é para mostrar o erro

Estou tentando isso dentro de um AlertDialog()

```
_showAlert(BuildContext context){
    showDialog(
      context: context, 
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return AlertDialog(
          key: _formKey,
          title: Text('Troco para quanto?'),
          content: TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: _controllerValor,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Valor "+_errorValue.toString(),                        
                        fillColor: Color(0xFFf5dcda),
                        errorText: _errorValue ? 'Error' : ''
                    ),
                    
            ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  _errorValue = false;                  
                });
                //Navigator.pop(context);
              }, 
              child: Text(
                  'Fechar',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red
                  ),
                )
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  _validarValor( _controllerValor.text );
                  print('errovalue '+_errorValue.toString());                
                });
                
                
              }, 
              child: Text('Confirmar')
            ),
            
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Função de teste de validação é essa:

```
_validarValor(String value){
      var valor = double.parse( value.replaceAll('R\$ ','').replaceAll('.', '').replaceAll(',', '.') ) ;
    
      if( valor < _valorTotal ){
        setState(() {
          _errorValue = true;          
        });
                            
      }else{
        setState(() {
          _errorValue = false;
        });

      }
  }
```

Simplesmente não muda dentro do `InputDecoration`.

Onde estou errando?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente utilizar o método `onChanged` mais detalhes aqui :https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Comment: Também não funcionou

Comment: Atualize a pergunta com código que não deu certo.

Answer (score -2):

Utiliza algum gerenciador de estado, recomendo o Get,

```
var erro = "".obs;
.........
Obx(()=>TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: _controllerValor,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText:  erro.value != "" ? "Valor ${erro.value}" : "",  ......

_validarValor(String value){
  var valor = double.parse( value.replaceAll('R\$ ','').replaceAll('.', '').replaceAll(',', '.') ) ;

  if( valor < _valorTotal ){
    erro.value = "erro";
                        
  }else{
   erro.value = "sem erro";

  }
```

}...